# EF Core 2.0 System.NotSupportedException: could not parse expression

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0, notsupportedexception

I have been getting lots of intermittent errors like below in my API (.NET Core 2.0) code that is calling a business logic (.NET Standard) which is calling SQL Server database using EF Core 2.0.

Can anyone please help me where to look at? This started happening 4 days back out of the blue where no new code has been added.

Is there any new Microsoft patch that has come in recently that might be causing this?

**EF Core Query:**

```
public Repository(IDataContextAsync context)
    {
        _context = context;

        if (context is DbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }
    }

public IQueryable<TEntity> Queryable()
    {
        return _dbSet;
    }

public async Task<int> GetActiveSystemUserIdByName(string userName)
    {
        return await
            Queryable()
                .Where(s => s.UserName == userName && (s.IsActive ?? true))
                .Select(s => s.SystemUserId)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

> System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression. Could not parse expression

> 'value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[Entities.Order.SystemUser]).Where(s => ((s.UserName == __userName_0) AndAlso (s.IsActive ?? True))).Select(s => s.SystemUserId)':

> This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported.

Comment: The patch is using EF Core 3 or EF Core 5. EF Core 2 is *very* old. Besides, where's the actual code? Perhaps the query is too complex to be parsed. Perhaps it can be modified easily so it can run. `t.maskedField1.ToLower() == __ToLower_0` is a *very* bad idea anyway because it prevents the database from using any indexes. If the column's collation is case-insensitive, there's no reason to call `ToLower()`

Comment: All those `.Where(x => True).Where(x => True).` are very suspicious. Did someone try to create a dynamic query? If a filter isn't needed, don't even add the `Where` clause. The server may be smart enough to eliminate all those no-ops, but why waste CPU adding them?

Comment: Same with `False OrElse (True AndAlso wo.Masked.Where`. What's the point? Don't add any unwanted filters in the first place

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Queries are not that complex. Besides normal windows server patching, nothing changed on code side and it has been working like this for approx. past 5 years.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I do agree that query optimization is possible, right now I am right to figure out what changed that might be causing this.

Comment: No, it didn't crash for 5 years. That's very different. The code reached a point where the inherent bugs finally crashed it. Again, what's the point of `Where(x=>True)`? If you see examples of dynamic filtering, they use `if(filterValue!=null){ query = query.Where(x=>x.Field=filterValue);}`. The `Where` clause isn't added at all. if it's not. needed. And the code shown in the screen is *very* complex*. Mixed up `AND` and `OR` clauses with dummy operands. Multiple dead `Where`s. Clauses that ignore indexes, like `ToLower()` and `Contains`.

Comment: `what changed that might be causing this` the query finally crashed under its own weight. We can't guess what the query is though. Post the code - query, entities, table schema, DbContext and configuration

Comment: What is `Masked`? A number? A string? An `object`? That `wo.Masked ?? 0` is very suspicious. Perhaps the type of `Masked` changed to something that can't be used in a SQL query. If the type changed to `object` or `dynamic`, how can EF know what to do? Is it supposed to return a field in `SELECT`? Or an entire object with multiple fields?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I understood you now, this is basically the error which is getting logged by .Net Core logging mechanism. Masked is basically a field on code that I cannot share on public forum. Let me share a query which is giving same error.

Comment: So post the code. `I cannot share on public forum.` of course you can, it won't be anything that hasn't been posted a thousand times before. Which means it's not protected by patents, copyright or trade secrets. You can't claim copyright on code used by millions of developers. At the very least create a *different* example that demonstrates this problem. Or at least post the `Maksed` property and its configuration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Here is the EF query. return await
                Queryable()
                    .Where(s => s.Field1 == param1 && (s.field2 ?? true))
                    .Select(s => s.Field3)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(); This simple query is also throwing this exception - System.NotSupportedException: Could not parse expression. How can .Net Core say This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select' is currently not supported?

Comment: `Queryable()`? What is this? No, this is definitely not simple. The important parts are missing, and the posted parts are buggy. And once again, what is `Masked` ?

Comment: And the error shows `.Select(s => s.maskedTable2)`, not `.Select(s => s.Masked)`. Is that field a child object? In that case you're trying to do the equivalent of `SELECT Table2 from Table1 inner join Table2 ...`. Did the field's type change recently?

Comment: Unless you post an actual reproducible example this question will be closed. You've already posted far more details in the error messages than the query that obviously doesn't match the errors

Comment: okay, I am updating the post.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Updated the post to make little more sense and using simpler query .

Comment: Looks like versions resynchronization. `Queryable.Select` detected as overload.

Comment: I think the column `IsActive` is a nullable column on DB, when you execute the query where the column has value no problem but when it encounter a null value it execute the right _true_ of `??`. Try to re-write the where `(s.IsActive == true)`